# Как с помощью анимации увеличения получить из одной view другое view?

Tags: android, анимация

Как с помощью анимации увеличения получить из одной view другое view?
Проблема в том что у меня есть две вьюхи одна меньше по размеру, вторая больше, нужно чтобы вторая плавно перешла в первую. Я делала это с помощью анимации, но проблема в том, что при увеличении до нужных размеров вьюха затем сдвигается влево, проблема думаю в параметрах анимации. Вот код с помощью которого я создавала анимацию.

```
animZoom = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0.95f, 1, 1.15f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animZoom.initialize(firstView.getWidth(), firstView.getHeight(), getWidth(), getHeight());
animZoom.setDuration(5500);
```

Comment: Вам необходимо детальней описать вопрос.

Comment: Смею предположить, что человек хочет сделать, к примеру, чтобы после увеличения ImageView стала Button

Answer (score 1):

```
animZoom = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0.95f, 1, 1.15f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animZoom.initialize(firstView.getWidth(), firstView.getHeight(), getWidth(), getHeight());
animZoom.setDuration(5500);
animZoom.setFillAfter(true);
```

однажды решил похожую проблему вот так

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, но этот флаг не решает проблему, так как если проделать процедуру еще раз, то вьюха снова уменьшается. 
Я ршила проблему таким образом:

```
animZoom = new ScaleAnimation(1,0.95f, 1, 1.15f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.01f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animZoom.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            secondView.setLayoutParams(lParamFirst);
//...
  } 
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
```